# How do I determine the high and low values in a series of cyclic data?

Tags: python, statistics

I've got some data that represents periodic motion. So, it goes from a high to a low and back again; if you were to plot it, it would like a sine wave. However, the amplitude varies slightly in each cycle. I would like to make a list of each maximum and minimum in the entire sequence. If there were 10 complete cycles, I would end up with 20 numbers, 10 positive (high) and 10 negative (low).

It seems like this is a job for time series analysis, but I'm not familiar with statistics enough to know for sure.

I'm working in python.

Can anybody give me some guidance as far as possible code libraries and terminology?

Comment: Deleted my answer. I knew I was missing something. You want all the peaks and troughs of the sinusoidal wave.

Comment: @pyfunc how you _you_ miss this, with a name like yours ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an overly complicated problem if you didn't want to use a library, something like this should do what you want.  Basically as you iterate through the data if you go from ascending to descending you have a high, and from descending to ascending you have a low.

```
def get_highs_and_lows(data):
    prev = data[0]
    high = []
    low = []
    asc = None
    for value in data[1:]:
        if not asc and value > prev:
            asc = True
            low.append(prev)
        elif (asc is None or asc) and value < prev:
            asc = False
            high.append(prev)
        prev = value
    if asc:
        high.append(data[-1])
    else:
        low.append(data[-1])
    return (high, low)

>>> data = [0, 1, 2, 1, 0, -2, 0, 2, 4, 2, 6, 8, 4, 0, 2, 4]
>>> print str(get_highs_and_lows(data))
([2, 4, 8, 4], [0, -2, 2, 0])
```

Comment: Not necessarily. In statistics and scientific measurement, you'll want to more carefully define your local maxima and minima than "whenever instantaneous velocity changes from positive to negative". This is because there will be noise in most measurements.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to familiarize yourself with some of the popular python science/statistics libraries. numpy comes to mind.

And [here](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-user/2008-August/017886.html)'s an item from the SciPy mailing list discussing how to do what you want using numpy.

Comment: There is no such thing as enough pie.

Answer (score 0):

If `x` is a list of your data, and you happen to know the cycle length, `T`, try this:

```
# Create 10 1000-sample cycles of a noisy sine wave.
T = 1000
x = scipy.sin(2*scipy.pi*scipy.arange(10*T)/T) + 0.1*scipy.randn(10*T)
# Find the maximum and minimum of each cycle.
[(min(x[i:i+T]), max(x[i:i+T])) for i in range(0, len(x), T)]
# prints the following:
[(-1.2234858463372265, 1.2508648231644286),
 (-1.2272859833650591, 1.2339382830978067),
 (-1.2348835727451217, 1.2554960382962332),
 (-1.2354184224872098, 1.2305636540601534),
 (-1.2367724101594981, 1.2384651681019756),
 (-1.2239698560399894, 1.2665865375358363),
 (-1.2211500568892304, 1.1687268390393153),
 (-1.2471220836642811, 1.296787070454136),
 (-1.3047322264307399, 1.1917835644190464),
 (-1.3015059337968433, 1.1726658435644288)]
```

Note that this *should* work regardless of the phase offset of the sinusoid (with high probability).