# How do I slice 1 cycle of sine wave using python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy

I need to do some data analysis by extracting one complete cycle from a sine wave graph.

I have some CSV file consists of like 100K Current and Voltage value. From this CSV file, normally I would plot it and manually extract for one complete cycle. Now I would like to do it using python

```
import pandas as pd

file_path = "/Users/Fang/workspace_wind/test_cycle/the_data/"

## read csv file, selecting the first column only that is I(current)
df = pd.read_csv(file_path+"current1.csv", usecols=[0])

## find the maximum value, for the index use idxmax()
max_val = df['I'].idxmax()
## find the minimum value, for the index use idxmin()
min_val = df['I'].min()


print max_val
```

I started with this code. So far, I managed to understand how to get the highest value and the lowest value for half the cycle. At first, I want to slice it from the first highest value to the second highest value (peak to peak) for a one complete cycle but since the amplitude is not always the same, this method of mine is not going to work.

This is the example of the CSV file --> [sample](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4i3HIPTmP91RlRQLTBKTU5pYTg)

The closest that I found so far is this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381744/how-do-i-determine-the-high-and-low-values-in-a-series-of-cyclic-data) but I did not really understand it.

Thank you for your help and suggestion.

Comment: Produce a minimal sample data?

Comment: hi @Divakar I added a sample CSV file if you want to try.

Comment: Slice between three consecutive zero (or mid-point) crossings.

Comment: hi @SiHa can you elaborate on that?

Comment: One complete cycle of a sine wave will cross zero (or whatever the midpoint is) three times. It's not too hard to do a bit of maths to find where those crossings are (and in which direction). So, find a +ve/-ve going transition, then slice from there to the next-but one transition (actually the next transition in the same direction), and you have a single cycle.

Comment: Since positive/negative transitions may be more difficult to detect for noisy data, I'd rather use maxima (or minima), for which one can use `scipy.signal.find_peaks_cwt()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it in NumPy / SciPy by obtaining the maxima of one of the two signals, e.g. I or V, since the period of a (periodic) function can be defined as the interval between two consecutive maxima.

Below there is some example code for calculating the period on I (`ii_arr`):

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.signal

# load the data and define the working arrays
# note the `.transpose()` at the end
ii_arr, vv_arr = np.loadtxt(
    './Downloads/current1.csv', delimiter=',', skiprows=1).transpose()

# since a period is, for example, defined from maximum to maximum
# get maxima indexes of `ii_arr`, the same will work for `vv_arr`.
# (you may want to tweak with the second arguments, see the docs for that)
ii_max_val = scipy.signal.find_peaks_cwt(
    ii_arr, np.arange(10000, 20000, 2000))

# just use normal slicing for the first two peaks
ii_period_arr = ii_arr[ii_max_val[0]:ii_max_val[1]]

# ... or for more averaged result
index_diff = int(np.mean(np.diff(ii_max_val)))
# `index_start` can be just about any other valid value
index_start = ii_max_val[0]  
ii_period_arr = ii_arr[index_start:index_start + index_diff]

# optionally plot the results
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(ii_period_arr)
plt.show()
```

Physicist's note: if they are `I(t)` and `V(t)` are signals from the same device, this means you could assume that the `t` is the same in both, so I would use the signal with less noise for the detection of the period and their index difference must be the same.
In your case, I would work with `vv_arr` instead of `ii_arr`.
I just tested `ii_arr` to make sure the code was working in the worst case scenario.

Comment: Of course, the I/O part could be done in Pandas as well.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I ma trying to understand your suggestion here. you write `np.arrange(10000, 20000, 2000)` . You started from index 10000 until 19999 with step 2000 right? can you explain why you use that? specifically for that `2000 step`.

Comment: I started with a number much larger than the noise fluctuation in your I array, and then I wanted to have a few continuous wavelet steps to make sure results were not an accident. The algorithm works by suggesting peaks that remain consistent for different width of the wavelet transform. You could read its documentation for more details.

Comment: I am sorry, can you explain a little bit more regarding the noise fluctuation? I am trying to slice a new set of data but could not really understand how to tweak the `np.arange` value. What is the base for me to input other value?

Comment: The initial and final values depend pretty much on the number of points you expect between two consecutive peaks: in the above there were some 40k points between one peak and the next one. So the idea is that you want to pass a (not too long) list of consecutive numbers roughly in that range.